# WebBrowser: IDropTarget

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I am looking for an example how to implement [IDropTarget](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679679(v=vs.85).aspx) within WebBrowser. As a 'base' code I will be using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20057829/2758677).

Comment: @Ondrej Janacek, all I have is [interface code](http://pastebin.com/sKFdPU86), I don't know how to 'plug it in'. I have done a proper search, but have not found any examples for this. The closest thing I found is [here](http://www.itwriting.com/phorum/read.php?3,425,2801) (17th post).

Answer (score 1):

In theory, you should wrap the original `IDropTarget` object, passed from MSHTML to you at `IDocHostUIHandler::GetDropTarget`, and return your own implementation of `IDropTarget`, which would forward all `IDropTarget` methods to that original object, with one exception: `IDropTarget::DragEnter`.

In your implementation of `IDropTarget::DragEnter`, you would check the `IDataObject` object which contains the data about to be dropped (`IDataObject::EnumFormatEtc`) and return `DROPEFFECT_NONE` if the data is not acceptable, otherwise forward it too.

I don't have a ready-to-use code sample for this. Feel free to experiment and post your own answer when you get there.