# How to enable Autocomplete for forms in a WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control, mshtml

I've been trying to enable Autocomplete for forms in a `System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser` control.

Internet Explorer provides this with the `Internet Options->Content->Autocomplete->Use Autocomplete for Forms` option. With this enabled, when you start typing "a" into an HTML  element, it shows a list of your previous entries starting with "a" (maybe "apple" and "android"). I want the same thing in my WebBrowser control.

I've implemented `IDocHostUIHandler` in my class, and made `GetHostInfo` set the `DOCHOSTUIFLAG_ENABLE_FORMS_AUTOCOMPLETE` flag, but the flag doesn't seem to do anything. Other flags such as `DOCHOSTUIFLAG.DOCHOSTUIFLAG_NO3DBORDER` work as expected, so I know that `GetHostInfo` is getting called.

Some people report success from setting this flag, while others don't: http://microsoft.public.inetsdk.programming.webbrowser-ctl.narkive.com/MSQ6nobe/can-t-get-autocomplete-to-work-in-hosted-webbrowser-control

http://www.44342.com/webbrowser-control-f125-t1436-p1.htm

I call `ICustomDoc.SetUIHandler(this as IDocHostUIHandler)` in my WebBrowser's `DocumentCompleted` method so that the IDocHostUIHandler interface methods get called by MSHTML.

I thought that it might be relevant to make sure that my application is reading the registry key `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\Use FormSuggest` correctly, perhaps by implementing `IDocHostUIHandler.GetOptionKeyPath` or `IDocHostUIHandler.GetOverrideKeyPath`as suggested by people elsewhere. I tried implementing these, but I could not manage to make either of them get called.

I used the Process Monitor tool to check which registry keys my application was querying, and `Use FormSuggest` was not being queried at all. It was trying to query `HKCU\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Control Panel\FormSuggest`, but modifying this key did not seem to have any effect.

Is there anything further that I could do to get Autocomplete working? Thanks.

Comment: Are you wanting to populate your own auto-complete word list, or simply display previous values the user typed specifically using IE?

Comment: @Loathing I want the same functionality that IE provides - displaying previous inputs that the user has made. It could share the list of previous values with IE or not, either way would be fine. 

I don't want to populate my own auto-complete word list programmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following worked for me:
(tested using my wordpress url)

Go to this stackoverflow thread and copy the `ImprovedBrowser` answer: [WebBrowser: Drag&Drop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20051892/webbrowser-dragdrop)

Then replace the `DocHostUIFLAG` with:
(the one in the original post only has a partial list)
You can read the descriptions of the flag values on [MSDN DOCHOSTUIFLAG Enumerated Type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753277(v=vs.85).aspx)

```
[Flags]
public enum DOCHOSTUIFLAG
{
    DIALOG = 0x00000001,
    DISABLE_HELP_MENU = 0x00000002,
    NO3DBORDER = 0x00000004,
    SCROLL_NO = 0x00000008,
    DISABLE_SCRIPT_INACTIVE = 0x00000010,
    OPENNEWWIN = 0x00000020,
    DISABLE_OFFSCREEN = 0x00000040,
    FLAT_SCROLLBAR = 0x00000080,
    DIV_BLOCKDEFAULT = 0x00000100,
    ACTIVATE_CLIENTHIT_ONLY = 0x00000200,
    OVERRIDEBEHAVIORFACTORY = 0x00000400,
    CODEPAGELINKEDFONTS = 0x00000800,
    URL_ENCODING_DISABLE_UTF8 = 0x00001000,
    URL_ENCODING_ENABLE_UTF8 = 0x00002000,
    ENABLE_FORMS_AUTOCOMPLETE = 0x00004000,
    ENABLE_INPLACE_NAVIGATION = 0x00010000,
    IME_ENABLE_RECONVERSION = 0x00020000,
    THEME = 0x00040000,
    NOTHEME = 0x00080000,
    NOPICS = 0x00100000,
    NO3DOUTERBORDER = 0x00200000,
    DISABLE_EDIT_NS_FIXUP = 0x00400000,
    LOCAL_MACHINE_ACCESS_CHECK = 0x00800000,
    DISABLE_UNTRUSTEDPROTOCOL = 0x01000000,
    HOST_NAVIGATES = 0x02000000,
    ENABLE_REDIRECT_NOTIFICATION = 0x04000000,
    USE_WINDOWLESS_SELECTCONTROL = 0x08000000,
    USE_WINDOWED_SELECTCONTROL = 0x10000000,
    ENABLE_ACTIVEX_INACTIVATE_MODE = 0x20000000,
    DPI_AWARE = 0x40000000
}
```

Then change the `GetHostInfo` to:

```
    int NativeMethods.IDocHostUIHandler.GetHostInfo(ref NativeMethods.DOCHOSTUIINFO info)
    {
        var ret = _baseIDocHostUIHandler.GetHostInfo(ref info);
        // must be done after because base.GetHostInfo(...) resets the flags
        info.dwFlags = info.dwFlags | (int) NativeMethods.DOCHOSTUIFLAG.ENABLE_FORMS_AUTOCOMPLETE;
        return ret;
    }
```